# CryptUnprotectData returns false when using JNI

Tags: java, c++, winapi, java-native-interface

I am trying to write a java application that uses the WinAPI CryptprotectData and CryptUnprotectData function. I am trying to accomplish this by using the java JNI. This is the first time I have used the JNI and I am having problems with decryption the data. I have debugged this in Visual Studio and found that the call to CryptUnprotectData is returning false and the function is returning NULL. I have no idea why it is doing this.

Here is the code:

```
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_Caller_Decrypt(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jbyteArray bytes)
{
   int len = env->GetArrayLength(bytes);
   jbyte * data = env->GetByteArrayElements(bytes,NULL);
   env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(bytes, data, 0);
   DATA_BLOB inData = {len, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(data)};
   DATA_BLOB outData = {0,NULL};

   if(CryptUnprotectData(&inData,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,&outData))
   {
       LocalFree(inData.pbData);
       jbyteArray buff= env->NewByteArray(len);
       env->SetByteArrayRegion(buff,0,len,reinterpret_cast<jbyte *>(outData.pbData));
       return buff;
   }
   else
   {
       return NULL;
   }
}
```

and here is the relevant java code:

```
String password = "Password";
Caller c = new Caller();
System.out.println("Password");
byte[] buffer = c.Encrypt(password.getBytes());
System.out.println("Encrypted: " + new String(buffer));
System.out.println("Decrypted: " + new String(c.Decrypt(buffer)));
```

I don't know why CryptUnprotectData function is returning false. Its been about a year since I use c++ and got hooked on java so i'm a little rusty so its possible I just misssed something but I was wondering if i'm just missing a step since this is the first time I have used the JNI. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is several big memory management errors in this program.

1) You call `env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(bytes, data, 0)` then continue to use the content of the memory pointed by the data pointer. This method may have freed its memory, probably overwriting part of its data with memory management information. That probably explains why the `CryptUnprotectedData()` failed. You must call `env->ReleaseByteArrayElements()` after `CryptUnprotectedData()` or after you have made a copy of the data.

2) You call `LocalFree()` on inData.pbData. This is the pointer to the `env->GetByteArrayElements(bytes,NULL)` and is managed by the JNI API. And must be released by the JNI API (which you did too soon using `ReleaseByteArrayElements` BTW).

3) You did not call LocalFree() on outData.pbData, which you should do only after copying the data using `SetByteArrayRegion`

Else, I do not know enough about the Windows Crypto API to know for sure if you call it correctly, but it looks right to me.